# jQuery .ready is not working

Tags: javascript, function

Can anyone tell me why this code wouldn't work? I have an input and I'm trying to check weather or not the input is "start". So I do... how ever nothing is working - not even the .ready but I'm new so I have no idea what the problem is. 

HTML

```
<form id="inputForm" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input id="input" type="text" size="30" autofocus="autofocus" maxlength="100" autocomplete="off"/>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var input = "";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inputForm").submit(function() {
    input = $("#input").val().toUpperCase();

    if (input === "START") {
        alert("worked");
    }

    $("#command_input").val("");
})
});
```

Comment: Can you please do alert(input) and tell me what it alerts?

Comment: The code seems right. When is the problem occurring? Is `input` receiving anything? Is the form being submitted?

Comment: Did you import jQuery? jQuery isn't stock JavaScript. It's a library.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/ready/ - What 4castle said.  If you didn't include the jQuery library you won't even be able to use .ready().

Comment: works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/cu7tn64o/1/  prob what the other commenters are saying

Comment: how are you submitting the form here?

Comment: @MikeS *"If you didn't include the jQuery library you won't even be able to use .ready()"* or any other line in OP's code starting with `$`

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you haven't included jQuery in your webpage. You can import it by adding

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Before the `script` tag for your code. (https://code.jquery.com/jquery has more jQuery CDNs too)

You really don't need jQuery to do this though. Here's the plain JS equivalent code [working here](https://jsfiddle.net/4castle/qpzfh2dd/1/):

```
var input = "";
document.body.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("inputForm").addEventListener("submit", function() {
        input = document.getElementById("input").value.toUpperCase();
        if (input === "START") {
            alert("worked");
        }
        document.getElementById("command_input").value = "";
    });
};
```

Comment: I like the option of using JS or jQuery.  Gave you an upvote for that.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/cu7tn64o/1/

It seems to work fine! As the other commenters have mentioned, this is likely because you have not included `jQuery` in your html file like so:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
```

https://code.jquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

1. First include the jquery file using **script tag** in your html file.
2. Submit the form using jquery or in the below case I have submitted using a button. Onsubmit the value is taken from the input field and compared.

```js
var input = "";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inputForm").submit(function() {
    input = $("#input-value").val().toUpperCase();

    if (input === "START") {
        alert("worked");
    }
    else
    {
    alert("sorry");
    }

    $("#command_input").val("");
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="inputForm" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input id="input-value" type="text" size="30" autofocus="autofocus" maxlength="100" autocomplete="off"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return false from the event handler, things ought to work.

```
var input = "";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inputForm").submit(function() {
        input = $("#input-value").val().toUpperCase();

        if (input === "START") {
            alert("worked");
        } else {
            alert("sorry");
        }

        $("#command_input").val("");

        // You have to return false HERE to prevent the default action of a                     
        // form -- send a request to a server, that is

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: The code works fine as is. Putting `return false` in the `onsubmit` attribute is fine. It's only an issue if they had added the event handler some other way.